# Lubuntu lagging

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, performance

Recently, I decided to install Lubuntu in order to get better performance on my laptop. I installed Lubuntu idealogical my Windows 10 home. At first, I thought I would be able to work faster and save battery power, however, I have seen the exact opposite. My Windows 10 and performed faster and my battery lasts longer with it.

Typically, I don't have to do anything to initiate the lag. The cursor will lag without me opening anything. It gets worse when I open Firefox. The process will freeze up entirely and typing will be severely delayed. Sometimes the cursor freezes for minutes. The computer warms up very quickly.

I don't understand. I have 4Gb of RAM and it is barely used:

[image: Lagging without using much RAM]

Anything I can do to fix the lag? The processor is an AMD E2 Vision on a Toshiba Satellite C855D using Lubuntu 16.0.4 LTS.

**EDIT**

I updated the post with some information requested in the comments. I believe my graphics are processor integrated:

```
AMD E2-1800 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics     : 1700.00MHz
```

lspci output: http://pastebin.com/2jSDw9uP

Apparently, syslog is too long to post on pastbin

Comment: You might want to use http://patebin.com, and post the contents of syslog and the output of lspci.

Comment: What GPU do you have? And did you install your GPU drivers properly?

Comment: Sorry guys, I'll grab that info.